# Ubuntu can't access web pages, even though it's connected to the Internet

Tags: 12.10

I recently just upgraded Ubuntu 12.04 to 12.10 on my laptop (I know, so late >_>) and immediately upon upgrading, my browser stopped loading webpages, throwing an error *instantly* after receiving a URL to load.

I tried pinging my DNS server, and it returned all my pings, which I thought was strange. If the DNS was working properly, why weren't pages loading? I checked my wireless network configuration multiple times, but each time the same behaviour returned.

Comment: Does the DNS server respond to DNS queries (try with `dig google.com`)? Does an alternative DNS server respond (`dig @8.8.8.8.8 google.com`)? Can you `ping` hosts outside of the network of your provider?

Comment: I didn't think of doing that. Thanks! Also, the DNS server I pinged was 8.8.8.8, and it worked.

Answer (score 1):

It turns out that my resolv.conf (`/etc/resolv.conf`) was borked on the upgrade, with just this one line, put in there by NetworkManager:

```
nameserver 127.0.0.1
```

Changing this to the servers I actually wanted to use made it work again.